# Why did Mary and Joseph offer "turtle doves" in Luke 2:24?

Tags: sacrifice, mary

this question was asked earlier, but I haven't the "reputation" to be allowed to post on the thread.  Josephus wrote that Jesus #2, ~30 years after the crucifixion of Jesus #1, was crucified by Vespasian.  In NT, the tale of Jesus #2 was conflated with that of Jesus #1, who was crucified by Pilate.  That is why one Jesus was rich and the other one was poor.

Truman

[Why would Mary and Joseph offer "turtle doves" in Luke 2:24?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/why-would-mary-and-joseph-offer-turtle-doves-in-luke-224)

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  I do not understand what you mean by Jesus #1 and Jesus #2 ???

Comment: please also change the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Josephus refers to more than one man named Jesus who died by Roman hands in these days. The OP refers to one of them as "Jesus # 2." If I guess correctly at the OP's meaning he was one of the leading priests in Jerusalem during the Revolt of 66-70, who lost his life to Vespasian's forces under Titus. He was not Jesus of Nazareth and the exact manner of his death is not specified. This Jesus is introduced in chapter 4 of the *Wars of the Jews* and his death is described in [chapter 5](https://www.biblestudytools.com/history/flavius-josephus/war-of-the-jews/book-4/chapter-5.html):

> To say all in a word, if Ananus [the high priest] had survived, they would have certainly
> compounded matters... And the Jews would have then put an abundance
> of delays in the way of the Romans, if they had had such a general as
> he was. Jesus [the elder priest] was also joined with him... I cannot
> but think that it was because God had doomed this city to destruction,
> as a polluted city, and was resolved to purge his sanctuary by fire,
> that he cut off these their great defenders and well-wishers, while
> those that a little before had worn the sacred garments, and had
> presided over the public worship; and had been esteemed venerable by
> those that dwelt on the whole habitable earth when they came into our
> city, were cast out naked, and seen to be the food of dogs and wild
> beasts... And this at last was the end of Ananus and Jesus.

**It is understandable that Christians confuse one Jesus with another, but this Greek rendering of a Hebrew name was actually quite common. No crucifixion is mentioned here, however.**